# keep on getting error in gamecenter authantication with ios8.1

Tags: ios, game-center, ios8.1

Suddenly in my project,I keep on getting error as below which works well before.
**error:**

```
{
     NSLocalizedDescription = "The requested operation has been canceled or disabled by the user.";
}, 2
```

I can see the `GameCenter` login window several days ago,but now it doesn't show again.

After search with error info above in statckoverflow  ,I found this has happened with ios7。3 times after dismiss of `GameCenter` login window,it never shows again.I reset the hardware，then it works。
It seems the same problem in ios8.1 with in ios7.Will it be solved in later version all it is  the strategy that never changed,means it does not fixed in ios7.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that if you switch to the Game Center app and log in there all will be good. After a third unsuccessful login attempt in `GKGameCenterViewController` (i.e. your app) that is normally required.